# Google Cloud Function can't install a python package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I recently published a package on https://pypi.org/project/gsuitefy/
I can install the package locally with no errors but when I add the package (gsuitefy) in the "requirements.txt" in the function I got the error:

```sh
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\n  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gsuitefy==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: )\nNo matching distribution found for gsuitefy==1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "84C90901"}}
```

Comment: The error message describes your problem. You are specifying a version that is not available to install. Edit your question, show your code and the requirements.txt. Read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gsuitefy package](https://pypi.org/project/gsuitefy/) appears to only be compatible with python2, not python3.

e.g. with a python3 virtual environment:

```
(venv) $ pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /home/[XXXXX]/venv/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(venv) $ pip install -v gsuitefy
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-8fvgqqfg
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-itd0y72w
Created requirements tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-itd0y72w'
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-hlzzykc0
1 location(s) to search for versions of gsuitefy:
* https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/gsuitefy/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: py2-none-any: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/ae/045782c202c626c3b76489a9a1b0b2bf398a956166fc0870719d653e7536/gsuitefy-1.0.3-py2-none-any.wh
l#sha256=44e92f23821eedcdae1f2748b468d1a321541b5ee45c49653adaec079f68369d (from https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: py2-none-any: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/73/b3b079b9a6cb15c8fb32f950ee504cf0e0af99a8ad11fec636b8aa5a0919/gsuitefy-1.1.0-py2-none-any.wh
l#sha256=1307c572a4ba2ce491cc9177d7c288c40f03ee5c051154863d441a5dd54f6300 (from https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: py2-none-any: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/15/b126d59768cc0b3ca9e276470f67a602f18767d180771bcbf1e137e17891/gsuitefy-1.1.1-py2-none-any.wh
l#sha256=720178a7ac6056d747cfe1c237ff2e9b3f3207268466c83671931a0e1766c985 (from https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/)
  Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: py2-none-any: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/3f/a2546b4ad2599a6af6304a963e4f3c4be9cf9785bab095cf35c161f1d420/gsuitefy-1.1.2-py2-none-any.wh
l#sha256=ff23036822e04c4aafa4c271ac4064400e3079b8df6a869d66284d58b9c0aeed (from https://pypi.org/simple/gsuitefy/)
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'gsuitefy': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gsuitefy (from versions: none)
```

On the other hand, this installs just fine in a python 2 virtual environment.

The [cloud functions python runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime) is based (as of this writing) on Python 3.7.1.  You will need to create a version of the package that is compatible with Python 3.7 for it to install properly.

Comment: Thanks @robsiemb it works. I need to use "--universal" parameter like that: python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal

Comment: @MarcosVidolin You should always publish a source distribution (`python setup.py sdist`) in addition to a built distribution, which ensures that even if the built distribution doesn't match the given platform, your users can still install from source.